# Routing between 2 routers with NAT (RRAS)

Tags: networking, routing, nat

I'm trying to figure out how to configure RRAS in order to allow my PfSense router to access a downstream routed network.

The Windows RRAS router is connected to a port on the PfSense router. I can ping Windows RRAS router on the WAN IP from PfSense router (from 10.0.10.1 to 10.0.10.2).

I can also ping between clients 24.0.0.2 and 24.0.0.3. I can ping from clients 24.0.0.x to PfSense Router 10.0.10.1.

I set up a static route in PfSense router to route 24.0.0.0/24 traffic through 10.0.10.2.

When attempting ping from 10.0.10.1 to any 24.0.0.x (including Windows RRAS LAN IP), Wireshark on 10.0.10.2 is showing that ICMP packets are inbound on the WAN interface, however it is showing (no response found!) at the end, and RRAS is showing an increase in count of the Inbound Packets Rejected. No ping response is shown on 10.0.10.1.

RRAS NAT is enabled on WAN interface.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm assuming the problem lies in RRAS configuration because the packets reach RRAS but are not routed properly.

Duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/910012/routing-between-2-routers-with-nat-rras

[image: Internal Network]

Comment: @Tim_Stewart PfSense has DHCP turned on the LAN subnet 10.0.10.0/24 which assigns an IP address to the WAN interface of the RRAS Router, hence its WAN ip is 10.0.10.2

Comment: I don't think static routing works through LAN interfaces on PFsense. I think you want it WAN <---> WAN. Your configuration would be more like a bridge with no routing.

Comment: Also, the rras lan side IP address Is publically routable. The 24.0.0.0/24 address range is assigned to Comcast in New Jersey. You need a RFC1918 private IP address range.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I know it's bad practice to not use a RFC1918 private range, but as long as there is a route in place that can inform the router where to send the 24.0.0.0/8 traffic, then it should keep it internally rather than hitting up Comcast. I'm assuming that as long as I got the routing piece done, I can always go back and change my addressing to an RFC1918 private range.

Comment: It's best to start with them. If a default gateway is introduced later it may cause unexpected results. Try it with a WAN interface going to the rras, make default any rules pointing at the rras for troubleshooting. Refine the rules after you know it's being routed.